# Install elasticsearch on OpenShift

Tags: elasticsearch, openshift

I installed a pre build `Elasticsearch 1.0.0` version by reading this [tutorial](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/searching-with-elasticsearch-on-openshift). If I start elasticsearch I got the following error message, Should I try an older version of ES or how to fix this issue?

```
[elastic-dataportal.rhcloud.com elasticsearch-1.0.0]\> ./bin/elasticsearch
[2014-02-25 10:02:18,757][INFO ][node                     ] [Desmond Pitt] version[1.0.0], pid[203443], build[a46900e/2014-02-12T16:18:34Z]
[2014-02-25 10:02:18,764][INFO ][node                     ] [Desmond Pitt] initializing ...
[2014-02-25 10:02:18,780][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Desmond Pitt] loaded [], sites []
OpenJDK Server VM warning: You have loaded library /var/lib/openshift/430c93b1500446b03a00005c/app-root/data/elasticsearch-1.0.0/lib/sigar/libsigar-x86-linux.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
[2014-02-25 10:02:32,198][INFO ][node                     ] [Desmond Pitt] initialized
[2014-02-25 10:02:32,205][INFO ][node                     ] [Desmond Pitt] starting ...
[2014-02-25 10:02:32,813][INFO ][transport                ] [Desmond Pitt] bound_address {inet[/127.8.212.129:3306]}, publish_address {inet[/127.8.212.129:3306]}
[2014-02-25 10:02:35,949][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Desmond Pitt] new_master [Desmond Pitt][_bWO_h9ETTWrMNr7x_yALg][ex-std-node134.prod.rhcloud.com][inet[/127.8.212.129:3306]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-02-25 10:02:36,167][INFO ][discovery                ] [Desmond Pitt] elasticsearch/_bWO_h9ETTWrMNr7x_yALg
{1.0.0}: Startup Failed ...
- BindHttpException[Failed to bind to [8080]]
        ChannelException[Failed to bind to: /127.8.212.129:8080]
                BindException[Address already in use]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you try to assign ES to port 8080, which already is taken.  the culprit in the config from there is `http.port: ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT}`.  just leave both `port` configs out of the config or assign the envvar some other port.  the default ports for ES are 9200 for http and 9300.

Comment: I read the discussion about the variable `${OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT}`. In my view, they edit that part of the tutorial, which describes the config/elasticsearch.yml by changing the variable to `${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT}`. But this hint dont work for me I get the same error as well.

Comment: @user3206010 yet your configured variable seems to be set to `8080` which is already in use.  If you do not have reasons to change the port, where ES is running on (and one rarely has), you can just leave the ports out of your config file and use ES's default.

Comment: Okay now there is no error, how could I reach the instance of ES  `curl -XGET 'http://XXXX:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'`?

Comment: check on the machine itself with ``curl localhost:9200``.  you should never ever leave ES open to the world btw!  ES does not have authc/z means!  just saying.

Answer (score 4):

You first have to stop the running demo application, which is already bound to 8080. This can be done with this command:

```
ctl_app stop
```

After running this command you will be able to start elasticsearch on the port 8080. However this is not recommended for production environments.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend installing ElasticSearch with this cartridge: https://github.com/ncdc/openshift-elasticsearch-cartridge

It will save you the headaches of manual custom configurations.

Comment: It seems the catridge is very old. Do you know how to update the catridge?