# OpenShift ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, openshift

I have configured an Elastic Search Server in Open Shift using Custom Application. Elastic server version is 1.4.2. I followed this [tutorial](https://blog.openshift.com/searching-with-elasticsearch-on-openshift/).
I am able to succesfully start the server and also I am getting connection from my java application. But when I try to create an index it is showing error.

Java code :

```
   CreateIndexRequestBuilder prepareCreate = client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("index1");             

     prepareCreate.execute().actionGet();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:278)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:197)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.index(AbstractClient.java:98)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.index(TransportClient.java:334)
at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequestBuilder.doExecute(IndexRequestBuilder.java:313)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
at com.lri.ecareagoradiscoovery.indexing.RemoteEs.createIndex(RemoteEs.java:51)
at com.lri.ecareagoradiscoovery.indexing.RemoteEs.main(RemoteEs.java:62)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the REST service to verify you can connect, and makes sure you're using the right port.

Openshift does not open a lot of ports by default, so that's likely your problem.  You can easily check with either CURL, WGET or a web browser.  If I want to see if ES is working locally, I just go to `http://localhost:9200/` and see:

```
{
  "name" : "Tommy Lightning",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.1.0",
    "build_hash" : "72cd1f1a3eee09505e036106146dc1949dc5dc87",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-11-18T22:40:03Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.3.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I would make sure you can do this before worrying about connecting and creating an index via Java.  The REST interface makes it very easy to test that things are working properly.

Post what you get if you get errors.

Comment: Hi, i tried to open the es url in browser. It is showing the elastic server details as given by you.

Comment: {
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Stryfe",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.2",
    "build_hash" : "927caff6f05403e936c20bf4529f144f0c89fd8c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-12-16T14:11:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: Is your browser on the same computer that your java client is?  Also, Elasticsearch 1.4.2 is pretty old, are you sure you are using the correct client lib?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TransportClient, ensure hostname matches **$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP**, which you can get from System.getenv().get("OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP"). [assuming you specified the same in ES config: **network.host**] .

[Update: based on input that Java application is on another host]

From [Install elasticsearch on OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063186/install-elasticsearch-on-openshift): Use this solution **only** for non-production use

- comment out network.host in config/elasticsearch.yml
- From command line, stop the default app running on port 8080 using `ctl_app stop`
- restart ES, now you'd be able to access it at port 80 from any external host. Again, this is totally not recommended since it leaves your ES open to the entire world.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that also but it didnt work.  Still getting the same error. what is the port number to be given ?

Comment: Are you running the Java application in the same gear as you've ES?

Comment: No. My java application is on another remote server.

Comment: yes i tried, but when i commented out the network.host, i am getting bindtransportexception failed to bind to :permission denied error